# Randomise an ArrayList<Object> in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, shuffle

Given that i have an arrayList of company objects. I want to shuffle the objects inside listcompanies. listcompanies has a list of object companies inside it. I want to shuffle the company objects inside the listcompanies arraylist.

This is my company object

```
public class Company {
private String id;
private String companyName;
private String currentTaskId;

private String task1_id;
private String task1_url;
private String task1_title;
private String task1_description;
private String task1_type;


private String task2_id;
private String task2_url;
private String task2_title;
private String task2_description;
private String task2_type;

private String task3_id;
private String task3_url;
private String task3_title;
private String task3_description;
private String task3_type;

private String task4_id;
private String task4_url;
private String task4_title;
private String task4_description;
private String task4_type;

private String task5_id;
private String task5_url;
private String task5_title;
private String task5_description;
private String task5_type;
}
```

This is how i store data:

```
//create a company ArrayList
ArrayList<Company> listcompanies = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 60 ; i ++){
   //Initialise a new company per iteration 
   Company company = new Company();
   //store data
   company.setcompanyName("Name: " + i);
   company.setcompanycurrentTaskId(i+"");
   listcompanies.add(company);
}
```

I tried doing this to shuffle listcompanies but it didn't work.

```
// I TRIED doing this for sorting the listcompanies
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(listcompanies, new Random(seed));
// nothing happened it did not sort the list of companies
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example where the entries aren't shuffled. Is the list empty? Does it only have one element? Is it coincidence?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis alright wait. I'll edit it

Comment: Are you asking about sorting or shuffling?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis shuffling the company objects inside the listcompanies.

Comment: You might want to change the comments in your code. How can you tell the entries aren't shuffled? Do you have output that demonstrates this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hey man thanks i re looked at my code i found the problem. I didn't put the Collections.shuffle inside the forloop.

Comment: Well, there ya go. Glad you solved your issue.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks you made me realise things haha.

Answer (score 0):

My question was a little confusing. Though i already figured it out the shuffle method randomises the data when it's included in the arraylist. Thus it was random all along.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Don't forget that this answer is supposed to answer your question and also to help future readers which have the same question/problem. Thank you.